# React Simple state management

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component with a small state. I want a button on click to change that state to something else. Right now I am seeing an unexpected token error and don't quite understand why.

Below is the code:

```
// Component to practice simple state mgmt
import React from 'react'

class Stateful extends React.Component{
  state = {
    flag: true,
    text: "I am simple text"
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Small State example</h2>
        <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        <button onClick={
          this.setState(
            prevState=>({
              flag: !prevState.flag,
              text: prevState.text.toUpperCase()
            })
      }>Click to change state</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Stateful
```

Comment: What unexpected token and on which line?

Comment: you shoul add your error log too

Comment: It was line 20 `Syntax Error unexpected token expected ; `. I ended up using my own workaround to make an event, bind(this) and call the event on click. Then inside the event manipulate the state. the way the accepted answer recommended. Don't quite get why I have to bind this to get it to work. But one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one `)` in your onClick function and you are not using it right. You need to use a function and invoke it for onclick event like this `() => ...`

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Small State example</h2>
        <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        <button onClick={ () =>
          this.setState(
            prevState=>({
              flag: !prevState.flag,
              text: prevState.text.toUpperCase()
            }))
      }>Click to change state</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I also prefer extracting onClick handler to a separate function. So our render method will be cleaner with this way.

```
handleClick = () =>
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        flag: !prevState.flag,
        text: prevState.text.toUpperCase()
      }))

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Small State example</h2>
        <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to change state</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning a handler for the click event. You are directly calling `setState` which is bad because you are in the `render` method and a state change causes a re-render, effectively creating an infinite loop.

You are also missing a `)`

So use

```
<button onClick={()=>
      this.setState(
        prevState=>({
          flag: !prevState.flag,
          text: prevState.text.toUpperCase()
        }))
  }>Click to change state</button>
```

Working demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/j2x9jm38y5